# Obter o userId e o accessToken do Instalgram no Facebook Developers

Tags: facebook, instagram-api

Tenho este script do `Instafeed`, que sempre funcionou muito bem.

```js
<script type="text/javascript" 
    src="<?php echo $dir_base; ?>js/instafeed.min.js">
</script>
<script>
    var userFeed = new Instafeed({
        template: '<a href="{{link}}" target="_blank"><img src="{{image}}" /></a>',
        get: 'user',
        sortBy: 'most-recent',
        userId: '111111111111',
        limit: 6,
        accessToken: '2222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222'         
    });
    userFeed.run();
```

Porém o Facebook resolver mudar toda a estrutura e, pelo que entendi, somente a plataforam `Graph` (https://developers.facebook.com/) é aceita.
Porém não consegui encontrar a documentação e não existe suporte.

Alguém já conseguiu coletar esses dados nessa nova plataforma?